# Populating a combo box from MS Access Database

Tags: combobox, vb6

Hey guys I'm really new to this but I need to populate my combo box's with an access data base as i am trying to make a cheap little checkout system and it doesn't seem to work.
If anyone could help me code my combo box and explain how it works would be amazing as I need to be able to individually select each one to be able to technically make a query to search for items and get a price from the db and being able to get change etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/745454/ComboBox-DataSource-Binding-in-Visual-Basic) should get you started in the right direction. It explains the steps you need to take to populate your combo box and how to grab the value of the selected item.

Basic terms you need to know:

> Data Source: This is used to fill the Items Collection of ComboBox with the data source. If we have a database as a data source, then we may use Table binding source as the data source for ComboBox.
>
> Display Member: This property from the data source is shown in the list as Items Collection of ComboBox.
>
> Value Member: This value is returned from the data source when Selected Value property of ComboBox is accessed.
>
> Selected Value: Use this if you want to bind the selected value to a property in data source.

Comment: That's for Visual Fred, not Visual Basic.

Answer (score 0):

See [Visual Basic: DataCombo/DataList Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260143(v=vs.60).aspx), which are different from the intrinsic controls which don't have a RowSource or ListField property.